# What is the word defining a part of a datastring/value for an isValid() method check?

Tags: python, validation, client-server, definition

I'm looking for a word to describe the part of a datapacket that includes date/time or date & time information which is used in a `isValid()` method to check if the datapacket is valid and geniun and not processed previously.

The SO question relative to this topic is [how to define "isValid" function with reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061396/how-to-define-isvalid-function-with-reason) but the answers do not include the conventional "word" I am looking for.

For example:

1. client sends packet to server.
2. server examins packet by extracting the timevalue from the data string.
3. server compares this value with the previous value.
4. if current timevalue is larger than previous the packet is genuin and the `isValid()` checks "True". Result: package processed.

The words that I can think off related to this are:

1. `token` - (secret set of values)
2. `datum` - (too general)
3. `date` - (too general and most of the times refered to a method via import datetime libraries).

Comment: sounds like you mean a verification timestamp?

Comment: yes indeed that is what it does. Please post it as answer ;-) Thanks.